# autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias of GooglePlace doesn't seems to work

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using `google place api autocompleteview` .

I wanted to restrict the search results to only `United States of America`.

```
    autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);


 autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(0,0),new LatLng(37.090240,-95.712891)));
```

This code doesn't seems to work . If I type `Sydney` it gives me results.

Comment: Bounds bias is not the strict filter. In web service you can set components restriction by country, but it looks like Places Android doesn't have this feature implemented. I found this feature request https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8611

Comment: Also, autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias() takes a LatLngBounds which requires arguments to be northeast, southwest; you're using southeast,northwest. Correct code:  autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(37.09024, 0),new LatLng(0, -95.712891)));